# File not found error in Asp.net 4.0

Tags: asp.net

On Local host,my solution works fine  but on server when i deploy ,it gives that file not found error. and the error message is something like this.`http://localhost:27375/favicon.ico`
I don't have any such file in my application.I tried to create on in the root folder but no luck.any help is highly appreciated

Comment: So you're getting a yellow screen of death for the favicon? Something doesnt sound right here.

Comment: Does it return an exception error screen or are you seeing this through some tool like Fiddler or developer tool in a web browser?

Comment: "http://localhost:27375/favicon.ico" is not an error message, but an URL. Maybe try to post the actual error message with the description what really happens and when?

Comment: Are you using asp.net MVC? Is ths error being caught by some global error catcher like ELMAH? If so then you will need to add a route into the global.asax file to ignore this file.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions,its an asp.net web app...

Comment: For some reason, it is looking for that file favicon.ico  ... I added a random file with that extension in the root folder and it worked..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your favicon.ico file should be in your root directory for the web site.

It looks like your application is still trying to connect to the localhost in order to display the favicon. Are you hard-coding your URL to the favicon with a `http://localhost:27275/favico.ico` address?

To build on what Internet Engineer said, using ASP.NET, you can use a relative path prefaced with `~` or `/`. So, you can use `~/favico.ico` or `/favico.ico` in order to reference your icon file.

Answer (score 0):

First check in web server if you can see the file directly in the browser:

http://productionwebsite/favico.ico

If the file is there, now you need to check that the code is using relative paths. Most likely this is coded using absolute paths.

Comment: Guys, for some reason, it is looking for that file favicon.ico... I added a random file with that extension and it worked..!